# Problem with calling a function only one time in unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

i'm fairly new to programming, and i have a problem with this code for my unity game, basically what happen is that the *first time* i try to call SelectGravity() it do it 2 or 3 times, after that it seems to work correctly, i can't figure out why.

IsRotating = false is called in another script and i'm using visual studio 2019 for coding, if this can help.

```
void Update()
    {
        Rotation = Input.GetAxisRaw("RotatoWorld");

        if (Rotation != 0 && !IsRotating)
        {
            IsRotating = true;

            SelectGravity();
        }

        Physics2D.gravity = new Vector2(XGravity, YGravity);
    }
```

For those who asked this is the script in which i set `IsRotating` false

```
public IEnumerator Rotate90()
    {
        if(changeGravity.Rotation > 0.1)
        {
            Direction = 90;
        }
        else if(changeGravity.Rotation < -0.1)
        {
            Direction = -90;
        }

        float timeElapsed = 0;
        Quaternion startRotation = transform.rotation;
        Quaternion targetRotation = transform.rotation * Quaternion.Euler(0, 0, Direction);

        while (timeElapsed < lerpDuration)
        {
            transform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(startRotation, targetRotation, timeElapsed / lerpDuration);
            timeElapsed += Time.deltaTime;
            yield return null;
        }

        transform.rotation = targetRotation;

        StartCoroutine(CameraShake());

        changeGravity.IsRotating = false;
    }
```

and i've declared it like this

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class ChangeGravity : MonoBehaviour
{
    CameraRotation cameraRotation;
    PlayerController playerController;

    private float XGravity;
    private float YGravity;
    public float Side;

    public float Rotation;
    public bool IsRotating;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        cameraRotation = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("MainCamera").GetComponent<CameraRotation>();
        playerController = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Player").GetComponent<PlayerController>();

        Side = 0;

        YGravity = -9.81f;
        XGravity = 0f;

        IsRotating = false;
    }
```

Other than this i don't call this function or modify this variable anywhere.

Comment: How are you asserting that `SelectGravity` is called 2 or 3 times based on a single update?

Comment: That code can't call `SelectGravity` more than once for each call to `Update`. If `SelectGravity` is being called multiple times then either you're calling it from somewhere else as well or you're calling `Update` multiple times. We can't help you with either case because we haven't seen the relevant code.

Comment: @Mathias i'm saying that SelectGravity is called multiple times because i've tried putting a Debug.Log in the function and it get printed 2 or 3 times in the console (it's usually 3 but sometimes 2).
@John i'm sure that `SelectGravity` is not called anywhere else, `Update`  is called every frame

Comment: It is hard to tell like this .. could you include the entire scripts and not just snippets?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem was that the script was attached to more than one object, consequentially `void update()` were called two times per frame.

Answer (score 0):

Check the `IsRotating` boolean. It should modifying somewhere else or bool decleration function is not correct.

Comment: The boolean `IsRotating` is declared as a global variable and set as false in `void start()`, other than that and setting it as true after some time (as said before in another script, but that work correctly) is not modified anywhere else

Comment: May us see the other scripts which is using `IsRotation`

Comment: i've modified the original question and added any other scripts where the variable has been modified

Comment: First of all I'm not 100% sure about this but I guess problem is `Rotate90` IEnumerator. You might calling IEnumerator few times somewhere and same  variables flipping and jump to the `IsRotating = false;` code and update method calling `IsRotating = true;`and          `SelectGravity();`

You can add one more boolean to check IEnumerator but i don't recommend.